# xsd.exe class generator issues with multiple xsd files

Tags: xsd.exe

I have multiple XSD files that describe an object. I want to generate the class from these objects so I can parse an XML that and create that object. I used `xsd.exe` that Visual Studio provides as follows:

> xsd /c efreight-CommonReportingSchema-1.0.xsd
>   ../common/efreight-CommonReportingSchemaExtensions-1.0.xsd
>   ../common/UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.1.xsd
>   ../common/UBL-CommonBasicComponents-2.1.xsd
>   ../common/UBL-UnqualifiedDataTypes-2.1.xsd

The `efreight-CommonReportingSchema-1.0.xsd` file :

```
<!-- ===== Imports ===== -->
<xsd:import namespace="urn:eu:specification:efreight:schema:xsd:CommonReportingSchemaExtensions-1.0" schemaLocation="../common/efreight-CommonReportingSchemaExtensions-1.0.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" schemaLocation="../common/UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.1.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" schemaLocation="../common/UBL-CommonBasicComponents-2.1.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:UnqualifiedDataTypes-2" schemaLocation="../common/UBL-UnqualifiedDataTypes-2.1.xsd"/>

<!-- ===== Common Reporting Schema Definition ===== -->
<xsd:element name="CommonReportingSchema" type="CommonReportingSchemaType">
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="CommonReportingSchemaType">
    <xsd:sequence>          
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:UBLVersionID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:CustomizationID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:ProfileID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:ID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:VersionID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:TransportExecutionPlanReferenceID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element ref="crs:SubmissionDate" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element ref="crs:SubmissionTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element ref="crs:ReportingParty" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element ref="crs:Consignment" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element ref="crs:TransportMeans" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>         
        <xsd:element ref="cac:DocumentReference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The cs file is generated successfully but when I try to parse the object, several errors occur like the following:

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ShipmentStageType[]' to
>   'ShipmentStageType1[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing
>   a cast?)
>
> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'TransportHandlingUnitType[]' to 'TransportHandlingUnitType1[]'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
>
> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsignmentType[]' to
>   'ConsignmentType1[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)

What I see from the errors is that something went wrong in the generation of the class. I think that several classes are declared twice and that's why the '1' is put in the end of the name.

Is there some kind of configuration change that I can use for `xsd.exe`? Or is the error caused by somewhere else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small script that loops the files and prints their filenames, so i can use:

xsd.exe /c file1.xsd file2.xsd file3.xsd

That should work :)

PS. I know i'm joining late to the party ;)